# DB connection pool getting exhausted -- Java

Tags: java, postgresql, connection-pooling

I am using Connection Pool (snaq.db.ConnectionPool) in my application. The connection pool is initialized like:

```
String dburl = propertyUtil.getProperty("dburl");
String dbuserName = propertyUtil.getProperty("dbuserName");
String dbpassword = propertyUtil.getProperty("dbpassword");
String dbclass = propertyUtil.getProperty("dbclass");
String dbpoolName = propertyUtil.getProperty("dbpoolName");
int dbminPool = Integer.parseInt(propertyUtil.getProperty("dbminPool"));
int dbmaxPool = Integer.parseInt(propertyUtil.getProperty("dbmaxPool"));
int dbmaxSize = Integer.parseInt(propertyUtil.getProperty("dbmaxSize"));
long dbidletimeout = Long.parseLong(propertyUtil.getProperty("dbidletimeout"));
Class.forName(dbclass).newInstance();
ConnectionPool moPool = new ConnectionPool(dbpoolName, dbminPool, dbmaxPool, dbmaxSize,
dbidletimeout, dburl, dbuserName, dbpassword);
```

DB Pool values used are:

```
dbminPool=5
dbmaxPool=30
dbmaxSize=30
dbclass=org.postgresql.Driver
dbidletimeout=25
```

My application was leaking connection somewhere (connection was not released) and due to which the connection pool was getting exhausted. I have fixed that code for now.

**Shouldn't the connections be closed after idle timeout period**? If that is not correct assumption, Is there any way to **close the open idle connections** anyway (through java code only)?

Comment: Does your code run in a server environment?

Comment: @c.s: Yes, of course. Jboss server.

Comment: Review your code somewhere connection is not closing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `timeout` variable does not seem to correspond to the time the connection is being idle but to how much time the pool can wait to return a new connection or throw an exception (I had a look at [this source code](http://kickjava.com/src/snaq/db/ConnectionPool.java.htm), don't know if it is up-to-date). I think that it would be rather difficult to keep track of "idle" connections because what "idle" really means in this case? You might want to get a connection for later use. So I would say that the only *safe* way for the connection pool to know that you are done with the connection, is to call `close()` on it.

If you are worried about the development team forgetting to call `close()` in their code, there is a technique which I describe below and I have used in the past (in my case we wanted to keep track of unclosed `InputStream`s but the concept is the same).

**Disclaimer:**

- I assume that the connections are only used during a single request and do not span during consecutive requests. In the latter case you can't use the solution below.
- Your connection pool implementation seems to already use similar techniques with the ones I describe below (i.e. it already wraps the connections) so I cannot possibly know if this will work for your case or not. I have not tested the code below, I just use it to describe the concept.
- Please use that only in your development environment. In production you should feel confident that your code is tested and that it behaves correctly.

Having said the above, the main idea is this: We have a central place (the connection pool) from where we acquire resources (connections) and we want to keep track if those resources are released by our code. We can use a web `Filter` that uses a `ThreadLocal` object that keeps track of the connections used during the request. I named this class `TrackingFilter` and the object that keeps track of the resources is the `Tracker` class.

```
public class TrackingFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Tracker.start();
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            Tracker.stop();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

For the `Tracker` to be able to keep track of the connections, it needs to be notified every time a connection is acquired with `getConnection()` and every time a connection is closed with a `close()` call. To be able to do that in a way that is transparent to the rest of the code we need to wrap the `ConnectionPool` and the returned `Connection` objects. Your code should return the new `TrackingConnectionPool` instead of the original pool (I assume the way to access the connection pool is at a single place). This new pool will wrap in turn, every `Connection` it provides, as a `TrackableConnection`. The `TrackableConnection` is the object that knows how to notify our `Tracker` when created and when closed.

When you call `Tracker.stop()` at the end of the request it will report any connections for which `close()` has not been called yet. Since this is a per request operation you will identify only the faulty operations (i.e. during your "Create new product" functionality) and then hopefully you will be able to track down those queries that leave open connections and fix them.

Below you can find code and comments for the `TrackingConnectionPool`, `TrackableConnection` and the `Tracker` class. The delegate methods were left out for brevity. I hope that helps.

*Note: For the wrappers use an automated IDE feature (like Eclipse's  "Generate delegate methods") otherwise it would be a time-consuming and error prone task.*

```
//------------- Pool Creation

ConnectionPool original = new ConnectionPool(String dbpoolName, ...); 
TrackingConnectionPool trackingCP = new TrackingConnectionPool(original);

// ... or without creating the ConnectionPool yourself
TrackingConnectionPool trackingCP = new TrackingConnectionPool(dbpoolName, ...);

// store the reference to the trackingCP instead of the original

//------------- TrackingConnectionPool

public class TrackingConnectionPool extends ConnectionPool {

    private ConnectionPool originalPool;  // reference to the original pool

    // Wrap all available ConnectionPool constructors like this
    public TrackingConnectionPool(String dbpoolName, ...) {
        originalPool = new ConnectionPool(dbpoolName, ...);
    }

    // ... or use this convenient constructor after you create a pool manually
    public TrackingConnectionPool(ConnectionPool pool) {
        this.originalPool = pool; 
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection con = originalPool.getConnection();
        return new TrackableConnection(con);   // wrap the connections with our own wrapper
    }
    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(long timeout) throws SQLException {
        Connection con = originalPool.getConnection(timeout);
        return new TrackableConnection(con);   // wrap the connections with our own wrapper
    }

    // for all the rest public methods of ConnectionPool and its parent just delegate to the original
    @Override
    public void setCaching(boolean b) {
        originalPool.setCaching(b);
    }
    ...
}

//------------- TrackableConnection

public class TrackableConnection implements Connection, Tracker.Trackable {

    private Connection originalConnection;
    private boolean released = false;

    public TrackableConnection(Connection con) {
        this.originalConnection = con;
        Tracker.resourceAquired(this);  // notify tracker that this resource is aquired
    }

    // Trackable interface

    @Override
    public boolean isReleased() {
        return this.released;
    }

    // Note: this method will be called by Tracker class (if needed). Do not invoke manually
    @Override
    public void release() {
        if (!released) {
            try {
                // attempt to close the connection
                originalConnection.close();
                this.released = true;  
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    // Connection interface

    @Override
    public void close() throws SQLException {   
        originalConnection.close();
        this.released = true;   

        Tracker.resourceReleased(this); // notify tracker that this resource is "released"
    }

    // rest of the methods just delegate to the original connection

    @Override
    public Statement createStatement() throws SQLException {
        return originalConnection.createStatement();
    }
    ....
}

//------------- Tracker

public class Tracker {

    // Create a single object per thread
    private static final ThreadLocal<Tracker> _tracker = new ThreadLocal<Tracker>() {
            @Override 
            protected Tracker initialValue() {
                return new Tracker();
            };
    };

    public interface Trackable {
        boolean isReleased();
        void release();
    }

    // Stores all the resources that are used during the thread.
    // When a resource is used a call should be made to resourceAquired()
    // Similarly when we are done with the resource a call should be made to resourceReleased()
    private Map<Trackable, Trackable> monitoredResources = new HashMap<Trackable, Trackable>();

    // Call this at the start of each thread. It is important to clear the map
    // because you can't know if the server reuses this thread
    public static void start() {
        Tracker monitor = _tracker.get();
        monitor.monitoredResources.clear();
    }

    // Call this at the end of each thread. If all resources have been released
    // the map should be empty. If it isn't then someone, somewhere forgot to release the resource
    // A warning is issued and the resource is released.
    public static void stop() {
        Tracker monitor = _tracker.get();
        if ( !monitor.monitoredResources.isEmpty() ) {
            // there are resources that have not been released. Issue a warning and release each one of them
            for (Iterator<Trackable> it = monitor.monitoredResources.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                Trackable resource = it.next();

                if (!resource.isReleased()) {
                    System.out.println("WARNING: resource " + resource + " has not been released. Releasing it now.");
                    resource.release();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Trackable " + resource 
                            + " is released but is still under monitoring. Perhaps you forgot to call resourceReleased()?");
                }
            }
            monitor.monitoredResources.clear();
        }
    }

    // Call this when a new resource is acquired i.e. you a get a connection from the pool
    public static void resourceAquired(Trackable resource) {
        Tracker monitor = _tracker.get();
        monitor.monitoredResources.put(resource, resource);
    }

    // Call this when the resource is released
    public static void resourceReleased(Trackable resource) {
        Tracker monitor = _tracker.get();
        monitor.monitoredResources.remove(resource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have your full code posted so I assume you are not closing your connections.  You STILL need to close the connection object obtained from the pool as you would if you were not using a pool.  Closing the connection makes it available for the pool to reissue to another caller.  If you fail to do this, you will eventually consume all available connections from your pool.  A pool's stale connection scavenger is not the best place to clean up your connections.  Like your momma told you, put your things away when you are done with them.

```
try {
  conn = moPool.getConnection(timeout);
  if (conn != null)
    // do something
} catch (Exception e) {
  // deal with me
} finally {
  try { 
    conn.close(); 
  } catch (Exception e) { 
    // maybe deal with me
  }
}
```

- E

Comment: I agree that the best solution is closing the connection and I have fixed the code for that. But my question is regarding the idletimeout value which the connection pool accepts in the constructor. Also, as the code is still under development, there may be cases where connection is not released (i agree it is not a good practice). So, there should be a way to get out of that situation pragmatically at one location (getConnection method) which will say me from connection exhaustion.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of connection pooling is to let pool handle all such things for you.

- Having a code for `closing open idle connections of java pool` will not help in your case.
- Think about connection pool maintaining MAPs for `IDLE` or `IN-USE` connections.
- `IN-USE`: If a connection object is being referenced by application, it is put in to `in-use-map` by pool.
- `IDLE`: If a connection object is not being referenced by application / or `closed`, it is put into `idle-map` by pool.
- Your pool exhausted because you were not closing connections. Not closing connections resulted all `idle` connections to be put into `in-use-map`.
- Since `idle-pool` does not have any entry available, pool is forced to create more of them.
- In this way all your connections got marked as `IN-USE`.
- Your pool does not have any `open-idle-connections`, which you can close by code.
- Pool is not in position to close any connection even if time-out occurs, because nothing is idle.

You did your best when you fixed connection leakage from your code.

You can `force` release of pool and recreate one. But you will have to be carefull because of existing connections which are in-use might get affected in their tasks.

Answer (score 0):

In most connection pools, the idle timeout is the maximum time a connection pool is idle in the connection pool (waiting to be requested), not how long it is in use (checked out from the connection pool).

Some connection pools also have timeout settings for how long a connection is allowed to be in use (eg DBCP has `removeAbandonedTimeout`, c3p0 has `unreturnedConnectionTimeout`), and if those are enabled and the timeout has expired, they will be forcefully revoked from the user and either returned to the pool or really closed.

Answer (score 0):

[log4jdbc](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) can be used to mitigate connection leak troubleshooting by means of `jdbc.connection` logger.

This technique doesn't require any modification of the code.